# Restar horas y formatear en c#

Tags: c#, formato

es la primera vez que escribo aquí.
el problema que tengo es que necesito restar 2 horas, por ejemplo:
19:15 -- 02.45
al hacer esto me da un valor negativo, -16.5 y yo necesito saber cuantas horas han pasado.
el formato tampoco es el correcto, desde las 16:30 hasta las 17:00 me da como resultado 0.5, cuando lo correcto seria 00:30. Es para un control de trabajo, donde hay empleados que entran por la tarde y salen de madrugada.
el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
var fecha1replace = txtEntrada.Text.Replace('.',':');
DateTime fecha1 = Convert.ToDateTime(fecha1replace);
            
var fecha2replace = txtSalida.Text.Replace('.',':');
DateTime fecha2 = Convert.ToDateTime(fecha2replace);
            
double horas = (fecha2.Subtract(fecha1).TotalHours);
            
txtTotal.Text = horas.ToString();
```

Ninguna de las dos respuestas me da una solución a mi problema. Tengo dos horas 19:15 y 02:45, con el primer código, propuesto por Antonio S.F., me da como resultado -16:30:00, por lo cual no es un resultado correcto. En cuanto al código propuesto por toto, me da como resultado 16:30, el formato es el que buscaba, pero el resultado de la resta, tampoco es válido porque me da 16:30, que tampoco es correcto. el resultado que busco es 7:30 que son las horas que van desde las 19:15 hasta las 02:45. Gracias a los dos.

Comment: El resultado de 0.5 creo que esta correcto, que no devuelva el formato esperado es otra cosa. Adicional si colocaras el valor que estas utilizando en `txtEntrada` y `txtSalida` y la salida que esperas basado en esos dos campos creo que ya ubieras tenido una respuesta acorde a tu pregunta. Favor de dar mas contexto a la pregunta.

Comment: Lo que necesito es que si un trabajador entra a las 19:15 y sale a las 02:45, por ejemplo, me de como resultado 7:30. desde las 19:15 hasta las 24:00 son 4:45 y desde las 24:00 hasta las 02:45 son 2:45, que sumados dan 7:30.

Comment: Entonces el ejemplo que colocas practicamente esta correcto, el problema viene en que en el convert solo se le pasan las horas y no la fecha completa (esto da como resultado que las dos fecha se crearan para el mismo dia lo cual esta incorrecto). Tienes alguna manera de que tanto `txtEntrada` y `txtSalida` tenga la fecha y hora. De esta manera el subtract que hace te funcionara.

Comment: Por ejemplo, si para el caso en especifico del que hablas agregas un `AddDays`, por ejemplo: `DateTime fecha2 = Convert.ToDateTime(fecha2replace).AddDays(1);` entonces el subtrat te devolvera que la diferencia de tiempo es de 7 horas con 30 minutos y 0 segundos. El problema aqui es no siempre deberas hacer el `AddDays`. Por esa razon te comente que es mejor que las entras de las horas vengan de forma completa, tanto con la fecha como con la hora.

Answer (score 0):

Basta con que user el objeto TimeSpan que nos permite guardar un período de tiempo; en tu caso la cosa sería:

```
TimeSpan TS = fecha2 - fecha1;
txtTotal.Text = TS.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo:

```
            //h1 y h2 son 2 ejemplos de variables con horas.
            String h1 = "15:30";
            String h2 = "20:00";
            //v1 y v2 es la hora pasada a minutos. Ejemplo: 15:30 = (15*60)+30
            int v1 = (Int32.Parse(h1.Split(':')[0]) * 60) + Int32.Parse(h1.Split(':')[1]);
            int v2 = (Int32.Parse(h2.Split(':')[0]) * 60) + Int32.Parse(h2.Split(':')[1]);
            //Obtengo al diferencia absoluta en minutos.
            int dif = Math.Abs(v2 - v1);
            //Obtengo la parte hora.
            int hours = dif / 60;
            //Obtengo la diferencia restante en minutos.
            int minutes = dif - (hours * 60);
            //h3 da formateo completo de la diferencia horaria en formato horario. ejemplo si hours = 2 y minutes = 9 h3 seria igual a 02:09
            String h3 = (hours + "").Length == 2 ? hours + "" : "0" + hours;
            h3 += ":" + ((minutes + "").Length == 2 ? minutes + "" : "0" + minutes);
```