# Restar horas en C#

Tags: c#

llevo varios dias (bastantes), dandole vueltas a como hacer una resta de horas en C#.
La cuestion es calcular las horas trabajados por un operario, el problema viene cuando el operario entra en turno de noche, por ejemplo si el operario entra a las 19:15 y sale a las 03:00, me deberia dar 7:45 horas. Solo puedo usar dos campos de texto, uno para las horas de entrada y otro para las horas de salida, tengo otro mas para mostrar las horas trabajadas. he probado este codigo:

```
              
              int diferenciaHoras = ts.Hours;
              int diferenciaMinutos = ts.Minutes;
              
              if (ts.Hours < 0) 
              {
                  diferenciaHoras = (ts.Hours + 24);
              }
              
              if (ts.Minutes < 0)
              {
                  diferenciaMinutos = (ts.Minutes + 60);
              }
              
              string diferencia = diferenciaHoras.ToString() + ":" + diferenciaMinutos.ToString();
              
              txthorasTotal.Text = diferencia;
```

puede que en ese codigo todavia haya algun fragmento de cosas que he ido probando, cosas que he encontrado por internet y no me han servido. o me salen resultados negativos o resultados que nada tienen que ver con lo que deberia salir.
Ademas en el codigo que he puesto, puede que falten cosas, ya digo que he hecho muchas pruebas, he borrado y he reescrito muchas veces, por lo que en el codigo pueden faltar muchas cosas.
Estaria muy agradecido si me pudieran ayudar, gracias.
Ah, el lenguaje es C#.

Comment: Esta pregunta, es un duplicado de una pregunta que hiciste hace 2 años, y se ve que seguis con el mismo problema. En uno de los comentarios, de esa pregunta, te estan diciendo que si o si necesitas las fechas completas, para saber que es otro dia. Si no, el algoritmo es muchisimo mas simple... si es un dia distinto, calculas la cantidad de horas hasta la medianoche, y sumas las horas del dia siguiente y listo....

Comment: hiciste [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/376977/324) pregunta sobre el mismo tema

Comment: Si, se que es un duplicado de la pregunta que dices, pero es que sigo con el problema y no consigo solucionarlo. de todas formas intentaré como me has dicho, pero creo que tambien lo he intentado con lo de la medianoche y no tengo un resultado satisfactorio. Gracias.

Comment: Entonces mostra un ejemplo claro, porque ni en tu pregunta anterior ni en esta, sabemos como vienen tus datos, que es esencial para resolver tu problema...

Comment: Mis datos vienen en dos textbox, en esta forma, 19:15 en uno y 03.00 en otro. Luego tengo otro textbox donde debe aperecer el resultado. El problema que le veo a tu respuesta anterior es que los operarios no siempre trabajan de noche, si trabajan de mañana de 07:00 a 15:00, que sentido tiene calcular las horas hasta medianoche. y el problema es que no puedo trabajar con fechas, no necesito la fecha, solo calcular el lapso de tiempo.

Comment: y como sabes que son de dos dias distintos? lo supones por que el segundo es menor que el primero?

Comment: Si, no lo supongo, lo se, porque el operario entra a las 19:15 y sale a las 03:00, al pasar de medianoche ya se supone que es otro dia, no? no se si me explico bien...

Comment: si totalmente.. entonces, o las contas a mano.. con un for, o haces lo que te dije, que es lo mismo que te dijeron hace 2 años [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376977/restar-horas-y-formatear-en-c#comment676606_376977) en tal caso, mostra porque te falla hacer eso...

Comment: Vale, creo que con esto ultimo, de momento, funciona bien. No lo habia probado, creo que es que abandone el tema. De todas formas gracias por todo.

Comment: Si lo solucionaste, pone una respuesta en tu otra pregunta, explicando como se soluciona.. Esta, la cerramos por duplicada...

Answer (score 0):

Por las propiedades de tu objeto `ts` se supone que es un objeto `TimeSpan`, si tienes un objeto `TimeSpan` si implementas en tu interfas que en ves de capturar la hora de entrada y de salida en un `Texbox` lo captures usando sendos controles `DateTimePicker` colocando su propiedad `Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Time`, esto para que el usuario pueda editar la fecha de entrada y salida y ademas la hora, de esa forma solo es necesario hacer lo siguiente:

```
    System.DateTime horaEntrada = dateTimePickerHoraEntrada.Value;
    System.DateTime horaSalida = dateTimePickerHoraSalida.Value;
    System.TimeSpan ts = horaSalida - horaEntrada;

    string diferencia = ts.Hours + ":" + ts.Minutes;
    txthorasTotal.Text = diferencia;
```